# Как исправить ошибку - ValueError: not enough values to unpack - при выборе значения элемента из таблицы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Как исправить ошибку выбора значения элемента из таблицы?

Уже давно разбираюсь и не могу понять что не так. Код:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    conn=sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sql = "CREATE TABLE if not exists  people (id INTEGER, status INTEGER)"
    cur.execute(sql)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        r = request.get_json()
        chat_id = r['message']['chat']['id']
        message = r['message']['text']
        write_json(r)
        if "/start" in message:
            send_message(chat_id, text = "Ну, привет")
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO people VALUES("+str(chat_id)+", 0)")
        elif "/db" in message:
            send_message(chat_id, text = "Второй вопрос")
            [name], = cur.execute("SELECT id FROM people WHERE id=?", (chat_id,))
            print(name2) # -> a
        return jsonify(r)
        print(r);
    return '<h1>bot welcomes you</h1>'
```

Ошибка:

> File "C:/Users/vnovitskiy3110/Desktop/webhook/app/main.py", line 47,
>   in index
>       [name2], = cur.execute("SELECT id FROM people WHERE id=?", (chat_id,)) ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got
>   0)

Comment: Запятую после chat_id и перед скобкой поставьте

Comment: @andreymal, так тоже пробовал, правда сообщение об ошибке меняется, сейчас обновлю

Comment: Ну да, теперь у вас `[name2], =` это какой-то бардак, непонятно что вы хотели тут получить

Comment: @andreymal, просто разбираюсь как работать с ботами в телеграмме и заносить данные в бд. Я плохо понимаю питон, но хочу разобраться.

Comment: @ВладимирНовицкий вы не с той стороны подходите к вопросу. Возьмите учебник по Python, прочитайте, поэкспериментируйте с примерами, а когда разберётесь с языком, беритесь за ботов.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, я в основном пишу на других ЯП, а тут решил изучить так как стало интересно написать бота и разобраться как это работает.

Comment: У вас ошибка из-за того, что в таблице нет объекта по указанному id, а конструкция в коде подразумевает обратное. В соседнем вопросе такая же проблема, попробуйте то решение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/874652/201445

Answer (score 1):

Надо сначала проверить, возвращает ли курсор результат, прежде чем его распаковывать:

```
rows = cur.execute (query)
if rows:
     pass # do something, e.g. unpacking
```