# Cчитать файл из бд SQLlite

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, sqlite

Дорого времени суток, нужна помощь с Phyton, не могу считать файл из бд(SQLlite), все это в потоке. Буду очень признателен за помощь.

```
[Your_id], = cur.execute("SELECT id FROM table WHERE id=?", (chat_id,))
print(Your_id) # -> a
```

> File "C:/Users/jone157/Desktop/webhook/app/main.py", line 65, in index [Your_id], = cur.execute("SELECT id FROM table WHERE id=?", (chat_id,)) ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0)

Comment: вы передаёте `chat_id`, чтобы тут же его и вернуть (не ясно зачем)¶ Подумайте, что код делает когда нет `chat_id`  в таблице.

Comment: дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/874559/23044

Comment: @jfs, я не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете в виду, я думал это работает так: Выбираю id из таблицы, который равен chat id. Буду рад, если объясните где ошибаюсь, смотрел по лабам с института, но решения в потоке почему-то отказываются работать нормально.

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка произошла потому что объекта по указанному `id` в таблице нет.

Можно вызвать `fetchone()` и проверить его значение и если оно не пустое (или если оно не `None`), вытащить из него `id`:

```
row = cur.execute("SELECT id FROM table WHERE id=?", (chat_id,)).fetchone()
if row:
    print('Your_id:', row[0])
```

Для проверки наличия записи достаточно вернуть хоть что-нибудь, пусть будет `1`:

```
row = cur.execute("SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id=?", (chat_id,)).fetchone()
if row:
    print(f'Your id {chat_id} exists!')
else:
    print(f'Your id {chat_id} not exists!')
```